# Problem dealing with double digits and legend

Tags: ggplot2, heatmap

I ask for your help because I've tried searching for an answer but failed to and
I'm new to ggplot.

Here is what I'm trying to do, without success till now.

I have to set up a Spearman Correlation Heatmap graph.
I'd like to prepare it with correlation coefficients rounded up to the second decimal point, and here is the (double) problem.

1. If I run the graph without correlation coefficients, the legend with the color bar is perfectly placed on the exernal, right side of the graph.

   But when I try to add the correlation coefficients with two digits rounding, it becomes tougher to manage the legend placement since it is placed right on the graph while the margin disappears, and I don't honestly know how to set it back like in the graph above.
2. In trying to set it up, using different formulas I've found to prepare the correlation, I've obtained heatmaps with slightly different colors, so I assume even the underlying coefficients are correspondigly different.

This is my second, maybe third question on the forum so I'm still "Ill-mannered" in showing my data, but I'll try as best as I can.

One kind expert suggested me to use the dput() command to show my data, so I'll try with that.
It's just a very simple table I've used just to try out the commands.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
library(Hmisc)
library(corrplot)

dput(Cartel1)

structure(list(A = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), 
    B = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 10L, 11L, 9L, 10L, 10L), C = c(20L, 
    21L, 19L, 20L, 19L, 10L, 9L, 8L, 8L, 7L), D = 1:10, E = c(2L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 8L, 9L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

The prompts I used are:

**A)** to prepare the  Spearman Correlation Heatmap without correlation coefficients:

```r
testtest <- as.matrix(Cartel1)
cormatrix = rcorr(as.matrix(testtest), type='spearman')
cordata = melt(cormatrix$r)

ggplot(cordata, aes(x=Var1, y=Var2, fill=value)) + 
  geom_tile() + xlab("") + ylab("") + scale_fill_gradient2(low = "orange", high = "green", mid = "white", midpoint = 0, limit = c(-1,1), space = "Lab", name="Spearman\nCorrelation") + theme_minimal()+ theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, size = 8, hjust = 1))
```

**B)** to try to set up the Spearman Correlation Heatmap with correlation coefficients:
(as you may notice, I had to round "3" and not 2, as in the original formula I've found on the net, I'm still new and I don't know why it doesn't round properly. I had to type "3" in

```r
cormat <- round(cor(testtest), 3)
```

just to have a *1* digit after the comma, but it's fine, that's not a problem if the result is correct.

```r
testtest<-as.matrix(Cartel1)
cormat <- round(cor(testtest),3)
cormatrix = rcorr(as.matrix(cormat), type='spearman')
cordata = melt(cormatrix$r)

ggplot(cordata, aes(x=Var1, y=Var2, fill=value)) + geom_tile() + xlab("") + ylab("") + scale_fill_gradient2(low = "orange", high = "green", mid = "white", midpoint = 0, limit = c(-1,1), space = "Lab", name="Spearman\nCorrelation") + theme_minimal()+ theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 1, size = 8, hjust = 1)) + geom_text(aes(Var2, Var1, label = value), color = "black", size = 3) +
  theme(
    axis.title.x = element_blank(),
    axis.title.y = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.border = element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks = element_blank(),
    legend.justification = c(1, 0),
    legend.position = c(0.6, 0.7),
    legend.direction = "horizontal")+
  guides(fill = guide_colorbar(barwidth = 7, barheight = 1,
                               title.position = "top", title.hjust = 0.5))
```

Thanks in advance

Edit: As Bastiàn suggested, here I show the changes in the graphs when applying the 3 or 2 value on `round((cor(testtest),3)`

[Value 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FW3xm.png)

[Value 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQLv8.png)

Comment: To fix the legend position, just remove the `legend.justification`, `legend.position` and `legend.direction` arguments in `theme()`, and also remove the `guides()` part, and your first plot becomes just like your first plot. In the future, if you have issues plotting, try commenting stuff you've tried to see how or if they affect the plot look, because in this case it seems to me that you tried a bunch of stuff and messed up your plot, but simply removing some of the stuff you tried fixed it back!

Comment: It worked just fine! Thanks @Bastiàn. Problem 1 officialy solved. Now remains to be understood (if anybody knows) how to make the two digits rounding